# Conan is looking for libA.so.1 instead of libA.so

Tags: c++, conan

I am packaging the `libA` shared library in Conan. It builds correctly. My `test_package` package copies the `libA.so` file down correctly.

Then, when it is run, Conan gives me the error

```
./example: erro rwhile loading shared libraries: libA.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

This is because the file is `libA.so`, not `libA.so.1`. When I rename `libA.so` to `libA.so.1`  and run `./example` the entire thing works.

In `package_info` of the `libA` `conanfile.py`, I do have

```py
self.cpp_info.libs = ["libA.so"]
```

I have also tried

```py
self.cpp_info.libs = ["A"]
```

but neither work.

How do I get my test package to look for `libA.so`, not `libA.so.1`?

Comment: please show a [mre]. `libA` probably has its `soname` set to `libA.so.1`, so thats what the linker (nothing to do with conan) inserts into your executable when linking with `libA.so`

Comment: Using only ["A"] is more than enough, don't use the full name. It seems like you are copying only libA.so which is a symbolic link to libA.so.1. The problem is not Conan, but how you built your library and what you are copying. You can use self.copy("libA.*", dst="lib", ...) to copy all, including the symbolic link.

Answer (score 1):

I did this in the package step

```py
self.copy("*.h", dst="include", src="src", keep_path=False)
self.copy("*.so", dst="lib", keep_path=False)
tools.rename("src/libA.so", "src/libsA.so.1")
self.copy("src/libA.so.1", dst="lib", keep_path=False)
```

The makefile for `libA` does set `libA.so.1` as soname. So I copied the `.so` file twice; once as `.so` and once as `.so.1`. The makefile that `libA` came with didn't generate its own `.so.1`. That's why I needed to make a copy. I have a feeling this isn't the optimal way to do this, but it does work.

Update:

Now I'm using

```py
self.copy("*.h", dst="include", src="src", keep_path=False)
os.symlink("libA.so", "libA.so.1")
self.copy("libA.so*", dst="lib", symlinks=True, keep_path=False)
```

Comment: you should make a symlink rather than copying the file

Comment: or ideally `libA.so` should be the symlink and `libA.so.1` the actual file

Comment: Your approach might work, thanks for sharing, but the recommended approach is using symlinks. You have the ``os.symlink()`` in python you could use in your recipe.

Comment: It's my understanding that conventionally, when you compile your program it grabs the soname (links) and saves it. In this case the soname is `.so.1`. Truly `.so.1` is a symlink to the most up-to-date backward-compatible file (e.g. `.so.1.5.6`) which contains the shared objects themselves. In this case, they never gave me the `.so.1.5.6` file, only the `.so` file with the object. So I must make `.so.1` a symlink to the `.so` file which has the shared objects. The program will link against `.so`, get the soname of `.so.1`, and then access `.so.1` which leads back to `.so`. Is this correct?

Comment: @AlanBirtles if I did that then how would my library link against `libA`? It would try to get the soname of `libA` and then fail because `libA` is a symlink, right?

Comment: No, unless you specifically check a symlink behaves identically to the file it links against, you pass the `libA.so` symlink to the linker, it stores the soname in your executable, at runtime the executable loads from the soname (which is usually itself a symlink)